# How to extract the endpoints of an interval in R?

Tags: r, intervals

I've searched, but I cannot find an answer. I want to further process the data of a plot I've created in R with `geom_bin2d`. I've extracted the bins (intervals) from such a plot using

```
> library(ggplot2)
> my_plot <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = x, y = y))+ geom_bin2d(bins=3)
> plot_data <- ggplot_build(my_plot)
> data <- plot_data$data[[1]]
> data$xbin[[1]]
[1] [0,3.58]
Levels: [0,3.58] (3.58,7.16] (7.16,10.7] (10.7,14.3]
```

Nothing I tried worked, including `min` and `mean`. How do I access the endpoints of such an interval like `data$xbin[[1]]`?

(Update: I turned the example into a complete test case based on a built-in data set.)

Comment: Consider providing a reproducible example.

Comment: [last example in `?cut`](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-August/170445.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
library(stringr)
x <- cut(seq(1:5), breaks = 2)
as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all(as.character(x[1]), "\\d+\\.*\\d*")))
```

or in you example

```
my_plot <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = x, y = y))+ geom_bin2d(bins=3)
plot_data <- ggplot_build(my_plot)
data <- plot_data$data[[1]]
x <- data$xbin[[1]]
as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all(as.character(x), "\\d+\\.*\\d*")))[2]
3.58
```